# What does 'Long lists' mean in flutter's list view builder

Tags: flutter

In the article https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/long-lists, they say you could use a list view builder when dealing with long lists. But what does 'Long Lists' mean? Is it hundreds, thousands or tens of thousands of entries? Or does it just mean a dynamic list?

In my code, i've been making decisions on how to build the app based on trying to use list view builder (e.g. i haven't been nesting lists within other scroll views as that appears to remove the builder functionality), but this makes my code more complicated.

I ran an app in --profile mode with 10000 ListTile widgets and found them both to be very performant during scrolling and initial load. I couldn't really see a difference from the performance overlay. So I don't really know what to conclude about ListView.builder.

Edit: Should note that I tested on a cheap Samsung Galaxy A10

Comment: In your ListView if there are 100 items, will you create that 100 items and set it as the children of your list-view when you initialise the listview or you use the builder to create those ? If you prefer the second way (builder) then we can call that a long list

Comment: listview builder just builds the widgets lazily meaning that it only builds it when necessary. eg: when the user scrolls down and the list has to be displayed. Using ListView won't be performant since you will build all of the widgets first before displaying any content. This would lead to a few seconds delay before displaying anything at all when you have 100s to 1000s of widgets to build in a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `ListView` and `ListView.Builder` extends `ScrollView` internally which Creates a scrollable, linear array of widgets from an explicit [List].

> This `ListView` is appropriate for list views with a large (or
> infinite)    number of children because the `builder` is called only for
> those children that are actually visible.

ListView calculates maximum scroll extent for all items in the list, that is actually taking time, but performance-wise not such an impact where user can see by their eyes.

The `ListView.Builder` should actually create the widget instances when called.
Avoid using a builder that returns a previously-constructed widget. So it's only calculating scroll intent for visible items which in case of `Listview` missing.

So there is no specific count that should be considered in-between, but if we have 100 items with the large widget tree, it will have some impact on memory usage of scrolling.
For it, memory profiling should be used.

Comment: I guess with your answer a 'long list' is just one that extends beyond the viewport?

Comment: ViewPort actually defines the rendering of widgets, how much load UI thread is having.